# C# code to Read XML From URL

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to read XML from a URL and store it in a file.I have tried this

```
public void getJobs(){
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string url = @"http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=5566998848654317&v=2&q=java&filter=1&limit=25";

        doc.Load(url);
        doc.Save(@"C:\indeed.xml");
    }
```

But for some reason it's not working. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This is entirely opinion based, and thus outside of the scope of SO...(to answer the question of if you have to modify your code every time the xml changes, that really depends on how it's implemented, but more likely than not, yes)

Comment: Well i'll try to break it down, Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the WebClient.DownloadString method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Since an XML file is nothing but text you are able to download it as a string and save it to an XML file locally.